# gwt ui settings in persistent cookies

Tags: gwt, cookies

how to store gwt user interface settings in  persistent cookies, so that user can get them on next visit? 
I have user interface designed using gwt. Some user prefer to see few columns from the interface every time they visit application.So want to store the changes made by user on interface using cookies..

Answer (score 2):

To set the cookie

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies.setCookie( name, value );
```

Retrieve the value in next visit

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies.getCookie( name );
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) is the link which explains the functionality of cookies and see [here](http://www.umingo.de/doku.php?id=gwt%3acookie) for GWT cookie example

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more.. as i am totally begginer in cookies and gwt... Any link which describes this will also do.. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have added some links to the answer :-)

Comment: Where do i need to provide this Cookie.. ? I have updated code for onModuleLoad() Method using above getCookie and setCookie method...

Comment: You said "Some user prefer to see few columns". So once the user select the columns that he wants to see you can create a cookie and add the selected columns.

Comment: Do i have to write independent java class (Cookie) when user selects columns from the user interface?

Comment: No..com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies class is available in GWT .

Comment: so i need to add code only in .com.google.gwt.user.client.cookies.onModuleLoad method for column visibility... no other coding is necessary ?